# ON DELETE CASCADE not deleting entry for foreign key

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite, cascade

I am running the below query in ideone

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHOR (
AUTHOR_ID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
AUTHOR_NAME VARCHAR2(18)
);

INSERT INTO AUTHOR (AUTHOR_ID, AUTHOR_NAME) VALUES (1234, 'MC GRAW HILL');
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (AUTHOR_ID, AUTHOR_NAME) VALUES (1235, 'J K ROLLING');    
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (AUTHOR_ID, AUTHOR_NAME) VALUES (1236, 'WILLAM');
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (AUTHOR_ID, AUTHOR_NAME) VALUES (1237, 'SHAKESPEAR');

---------------------------------
CREATE TABLE BOOK 
(
BOOK_ID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
BOOK_NAME VARCHAR2(15),
AUTHOR_ID NUMBER(5),
CONSTRAINT author_fk
FOREIGN KEY (AUTHOR_ID) REFERENCES AUTHOR(AUTHOR_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO BOOK (BOOK_ID, BOOK_NAME, AUTHOR_ID) 
    VALUES (10001, 'SOFTWARE DEVELOPEMENT', 1234);
INSERT INTO BOOK (BOOK_ID, BOOK_NAME, AUTHOR_ID) 
    VALUES (10002, 'HARRY POTTER', 1235);
INSERT INTO BOOK (BOOK_ID, BOOK_NAME, AUTHOR_ID) 
    VALUES (10003, 'TO BE OR NOT TO BE', 1237);
INSERT INTO BOOK (BOOK_ID, BOOK_NAME, AUTHOR_ID) 
    VALUES (10004, 'PROJECT MANAGEMENT', 1234);
```

After creating these entries, when I try to delete the entries in AUTHOR Table by using following command:

```
DELETE FROM AUTHOR WHERE AUTHOR_ID = 1234;


Select * from book ;

10001|SOFTWARE DEVELOPEMENT|1234
10002|HARRY POTTER         |1235
10003|TO BE OR NOT TO BE   |1237
10004|PROJECT MANAGEMENT   |1234
```

and

```
Select * from author ;

1235|J K ROLLING
1236|WILLAM
1237|SHAKESPEAR
```

the entry from parent table is deleted but their is no delete cascade effect in child table (BOOK table).
Can someone help me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: The shown code works for me. Are you sure you have data that should be deleted?

Answer (score 4):

Aftee searching the Ideone FAQ, it seems that it uses Sqlite3 for the SQL language.

Sqlite needs `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` to enable foreign keys checks. As they say in their docs: [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) :

> Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled, it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the `PRAGMA foreign_keys` command. For example:
>
> ```
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
> ```

Tested at: [Ideone](https://ideone.com/avUWHE)