# SQLite fails to delete the foreign keys with the cascade delete

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite

I have a simple SQLite database with a foreign key on a master table. This table is a relational table to help mapping Table A to Table B.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "PERSON" 
(
 "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 "NAME" TEXT NOT NULL,
 "SURNMAE" TEXT NOT NULL,
 "LAST_MOD" TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "DEPARTMENT" 
(
 "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 "DEPNAME" TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "PERSON_DEPARTMENT" 
(
 "PER_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
 "DEP_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL
               FOREIGN KEY (PER_ID)
                  REFERENCES PERSON (PER_ID)
                     ON UPDATE CASCADE
                     ON DELETE CASCADE
                  FOREIGN KEY (DEP_ID)
                  REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (DEP_ID)
                     ON UPDATE CASCADE
                     ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now so long I delete a couple of records using the visual interface, rows in the related table are deleted too as well as enforced for not being orphan.

However, if I do a truncate via a `DELETE FROM PERSON`, all the records in the related table remain in place. I can't understand why.
Any hint?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but it is mentioned on: https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/truncate.php that a delete without a where clause is optimized for fast deletion. I guess that foreign keys are not evaluated during that process. Is the child table still in a valid state after such operation? It seems a bit odd to not implement truncate and instead use an optimization like that. Looks like more than enough rope ...

Comment: Hi @Lennart the table is still valid, but clearly there is a huge inconsistency at this point because half of the data no longer exist. I tried to enable the recursive trigger just in case I need to delete this again in the future, but I'm not sure this will work.

Comment: @Lennart The truncate optimization is not applied when there are foreign keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ON DELETE CASCADE not deleting entry for foreign key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94134/on-delete-cascade-not-deleting-entry-for-foreign-key)

Comment: Deleting with WHERE cascades the delete according to OP

Comment: @CL sounds like a duplicate, though the question is very old. In any case my PRAGMA Foregign_keys was ON since the beginning. And as said already a WHERE clause makes it working.